# Ant classNotFound exception with Junit Java

Tags: java, xml, junit, ant, classnotfoundexception

I am getting a `ClassNotFound` exception when I try to run my unit test.
Here is the .xml script for running the test.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Embedded CST316 Project Test Build" default="targets" basedir=".">

    <!-- set global properties for this build -->
    <property name="src" location="airAutomation/src" />
    <!-- <property name="test" location="airAutomation/test" /> -->
    <property name="test" location="airAutomation/testAirUI/airUI/pkg" />
    <property name="build" location="airAutomation/classes" />
    <property name="test.dir" location="airAutomation/classes/tests" />
    <property name="test.report.dir" location="airAutomation/testreport" />

    <path id="junit.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${build}" />
        <pathelement location="airAutomation/lib/xbjlib-1.0.1.jar" />
        <pathelement location="airAutomation/lib/junit-4.12.jar" />
        <pathelement location="airAutomation/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="targets">
        <!-- Display available targets -->
        <echo message="targets are clean, prepare, compile, junit"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <!-- Delete the ${build} directory tree -->
        <delete dir="${build}" />
        <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" />
        <!-- <delete dir="${test}" /> --> 
    </target>

    <target name="prepare">
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp/>
        <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
        <!-- <mkdir dir="${test}" /> -->
        <mkdir dir="${test.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean, prepare"
        description="Compile Unit Tests">
        <!-- Compile all classes -->
        <javac srcdir="${src}"
            includeantruntime="false"
            destdir="${build}" >
            <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${test}"
            includeantruntime="false"
            destdir="${test.dir}" >
            <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="junit" depends="compile"
        description="Execute Unit Tests">
        <!-- Run Junit tests -->
        <junit printsummary="yes" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
            <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${test.dir}" />
             </classpath>
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
                <fileset dir="airAutomation/testAirUI/airUI/pkg/">
                    <include name="**Test*.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

</project>
```

Here is the output from the end of the xml.

```
<error message="roomTest" type="java.lang.ClassNotFoundException">
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: roomTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
</error>
```

The test is in the folder "airAutomation/testAirUI/airUI/pkg/"

Would I need to specify this folder somewhere else (I created some folders to hold the output of the tests)?

Comment: Does your script compile roomTest.java?

Comment: Yes. It compiles just fine.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not seeing where your build script compiles anything in the airAutomation/testAirUI folder.

Comment: I modified the script to compile from the testAirUI folder. I am getting the .class file in the test.dir folder I created, but still getting the classNotFound Exception. Do I have some path incorrect.

Comment: Are the tests in a package?

Comment: At the moment there is only one test, but it is not in a package.